# StreamPlot - streamlines are outside the plotting domain

Tags: plotting, finite-element-method, mesh

I am trying to plot some streamlines, where the domain is given by a mesh. The results are good, but sometimes there are streamlines, that do not end at the boundary of the domain and are plotted a little bit outside. Here is MVE:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]

\[Alpha] = Pi/4;
Q = {{Cos[\[Alpha]], -Sin[\[Alpha]]}, {Sin[\[Alpha]], Cos[\[Alpha]]}}; 
d = Q.{1, 0};

\[CapitalOmega] = RegionDifference[Rectangle[{0, 0}, {1, 1}], Ellipsoid[{1/2, 1/2}, {1/6, 1/50}]];
mesh = ToElementMesh[\[CapitalOmega]];
StreamPlot[d, {x, y} \[Element] mesh, StreamPoints -> Coarse, StreamMarkers -> "Segment"]
```

This produces the following plot:
[image: MVE]
As you can see, there is a small line inside the ellipse. Is there a way, how to remove it?

**EDIT** Another example:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]

\[Alpha] = Pi/4*x;
Q = {{Cos[\[Alpha]], -Sin[\[Alpha]]}, {Sin[\[Alpha]], Cos[\[Alpha]]}}; 
vars = {{u[x, y], v[x, y]}, {x, y}};
pars = <|"MaterialModel" -> "NeoHookeanIsotropic", "LameParameter" -> 10^9, "ShearModulus" -> 5*10^8, "Thickness" -> 1|>;

\[CapitalOmega] = Rectangle[{0, 0}, {1, 1}];
mesh = ToElementMesh[\[CapitalOmega]];
pde := {SolidMechanicsPDEComponent[vars, pars] == SolidBoundaryLoadValue[x == 1, vars, pars, <|"Pressure" -> {p, 0}|>], SolidFixedCondition[x == 0, vars, pars]};
displacement = NDSolveValue[pde /. p -> 3*10^8, {u[x, y], v[x, y]}, {x, y} \[Element] \[CapitalOmega]];

deformedMesh = ElementMeshDeformation[mesh, displacement, "ScalingFactor" -> 1];
dispGrad = Map[Grad[#, {x, y}] &, displacement];
direction = Partition[ElementMeshInterpolation[deformedMesh, #["ValuesOnGrid"]][x, y] & /@ Flatten[dispGrad][[All, 0]], 2] . Q . {1, 0} + Q.{1, 0};
StreamPlot[direction, {x, y} \[Element] deformedMesh, StreamPoints -> Coarse, StreamMarkers -> "Segment"]
```

This produces the following plot. One streamline in the lower right corner starts outside of the domain.
[image: another example]

Comment: The second example doesn't work for me -- I get `FindRoot::jsing1`, `FindRoot::sszero` and `Set::shape` errors and it shows a square region.

Comment: ^^ is the second example working for everyone else?  `$Version = "13.2.1 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (January 27, 2023)"`

Comment: I think you should report these issues to WRI.

Comment: @ChrisK, MKL ( hence Paradiso) does not work on ARM. Use Rosetta .

Comment: @ChrisK, even though it's a known limitation, you could report it to create some traction for this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- At first, we use `reg=MeshRegion@deformedMesh`,not only `deformedMesh`.
- We use `SignedRegionDistance` to define a `RegionFunction` to mask the outside of the region `MeshRegion@deformedMesh`.

```
reg = MeshRegion@deformedMesh;
streamplot = 
  StreamPlot[direction, {x, y} ∈ reg, StreamPoints -> Coarse,
    StreamMarkers -> "Segment"];
dist = SignedRegionDistance[reg];
masking = 
  RegionPlot[dist@{x, y} >= 10^-3, {x, 0, 1.25}, {y, 0, 1.2}, 
   PlotStyle -> White, BoundaryStyle -> None];
boundary = RegionPlot[RegionBoundary[reg], PlotStyle -> Blue];
Show[streamplot, masking, boundary]
```

[image]

*
[image]

Comment: Looks like this works. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

Just change your mesh definition to

```
mesh = ToElementMesh[\[CapitalOmega], MaxCellMeasure -> .1];
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but the different mesh causes me some problems in other parts of the code (mainly with ElementMeshDeformation). Do you think it is possible to achieve the same result without changing the mesh?

Comment: Is option `Coarse` necessary?

Comment: It is not, but it is appreciated. I use the StreamPlot to plot direction of fibers in material and it looks much better, if the number of streamlines is lower.

Comment: Aren't there easier ways to draw a group of straight lines?

Comment: Straight lines in a square? Probably yes, but this is just a MVE. In the more complex cases, the lines are not necessarily straight and the domain is more complicated. I use Mathematica's solid mechanics framework to model deformations o fiber-reinforced materials (only in 2D). After I solve the equations, I would like to plot the fibers, for which I use the StreamPlot. The fibers are not alway straight and the domain is given by the deformed material (I use ElementMeshDeformation to deform the mesh).

Comment: I have added another example.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of making `StreamPlot` deal with the `Region`, how about just covering up the excluded region afterwards?

```
Show[
  StreamPlot[d, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, StreamPoints -> Coarse, StreamMarkers -> "Segment"],
  Graphics[{White, EdgeForm[Blue], Ellipsoid[{1/2, 1/2}, {1/6, 1/50}]}]
]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This works only in this specific situation. It doesn't solve more complicated problems. I have added another example into the post.